# Flutter Setting the value in another class to setState?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
class RestaurantApi{  
Future<List<Food>> getMoreData(bool moreAviable, bool gettingMoreFoods,
      List<Food> foods, int pageSize, Function callBack) async {
    if (moreAviable == false) {
      return null;
    }
    HTTP REQUEST PROCEDURES.....
    if (gettingMoreFoods == true) {
      return null;
    }
      gettingMoreFoods = false;
  }
}

class _DemoPaginationState extends State<DemoPagination> {
return FutureBuilder(
        future: restaurantApi.getMoreData(moreAviable, gettingMoreFoods, foods, pageSize),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Food>> snapshot) {
               ......
        }
}
```

In the getMoreData () method of the RestaurantApi class, gettingMoreFoods = false; I need to set the field to **setState**. How will I do this in another classroom?